# 'Grenade' projection based on angle + bounce

Tags: optimization, physics, game-physics, physics-engine, cartesian-coordinates

I'm having some trouble with synthesizing an advanced object projection formula. I have already figured out few basic physic simulation formulas such as:

- **Velocity of object**: 
  `x += cos(angle);
  y += sin(angle);`
  *where **angle** can be obtained by either mouse position or with tan(...target and intial values)

but that only travels straight based on the angle.

- **Gravity**:
  `Yvelocity = Yvelocity - gravity;
  if(!isHitPlatform) {
  Obj.y += YVelocity
  }`
- **Bounce**:`// No point if we've not been sized...
                  if (height > 0) {
                      // Are we bouncing...
                      if (bounce) {
                          // Add the vDelta to the yPos
                          // vDelta may be postive or negative, allowing
                          // for both up and down movement...
                          yPos += vDelta;
                          // Add the gravity to the vDelta, this will slow down
                          // the upward movement and speed up the downward movement...
                          // You may wish to place a max speed to this
                          vDelta += gDelta;
                          // If the sprite is not on the ground...
                          if (yPos + SPRITE_HEIGHT >= height) {
                              // Seat the sprite on the ground
                              yPos = height - SPRITE_HEIGHT;
                              // If the re-bound delta is 0 or more then we've stopped
                              // bouncing...
                              if (rbDelta >= 0) {
                                  // Stop bouncing...
                                  bounce = false;
                              } else {
                                  // Add the re-bound degregation delta to the re-bound delta
                                  rbDelta += rbDegDelta;
                                  // Set the vDelta...
                                  vDelta = rbDelta;
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }`

I need help way to combine these three formulas to create an efficient and lightweight algorithm that allows an object to be projected in an arch determined by the angle, yet continues to bounce a few times before coming to a stop, all with an acceptable amount of discontinuity between each point. ***Note**: Having the grenade be determined by a f(x) = -x^2 formula creates a larger jump discontinuity as the slope increases, forcing you to reverse the formula to find x = +-y value (to determine whether + or -, check the bounds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like:

```
class granade
{
    private static final double dt = 0.1; // or similar

    private double speedx;
    private double speedy;
    private double positionx;
    private double positiony;

    public granade(double v, double angle)
    {
        speedx = v * Math.cos(angle);
        speedy = v * Math.sin(angle);

        positionx = 0;
        positiony = 0;
    }

    public void nextframe()
    {
        // update speed: v += a*dt
        speedy -= gravity* dt;

        // update position: pos += v*dt
        positionx += speedx * dt;
        double newpositiony = positiony + speedy*dt;

        // bounce if hit ground
        if (newpositiony > 0)
            positiony = newpositiony;
        else {
            // bounce vertically
            speedy *= -1;
            positiony = -newpositiony;
        }
    }

    public void draw() { /* TODO */ }
}
```

OT: avoid Math.atan(y/x), use Math.atan2(y, x)

Comment: What are the advantages of using Math.atan2(y,x) over Math.atan(y/x.0) (*note: double division instead of integer division)?

Comment: i can think of three: 1) atan2(1, 0) = pi/2;  atan(1/0) => ExceptionDivisionByZero. 2) atan is extremely inaccurate with angles around 90°. 3) atan2(-1, 1)!=atan2(1, -1) but atan(-1/1)=atan(1/-1)

Comment: Okay, I see, the atan2 function is more advantageous because of it's ability to handle the **ambiguous cases of triangles** and other small exceptions. The normal atan function is more like the answer a typical calculator will give you.

Comment: Additionally, what does the **dt** variable in your code modify in the algorithm? Is that some sort of gravity factor?

Comment: dt is the time in seconds between two frames... you can set dt=1.0/FPS if you want a realtime simulation or some fixed 0.1 0.01 (try some values and see how it goes)

Comment: Also as a note to other viewers for this thread: You can emulate a "deflect" of the grenade like object off a "wall" like structure by adding Pi/2 (90 degrees) to the angle parameter.